# Sort GridView textbox column that is allowed to edit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

I have a GridView with 5 columns. Two are textbox fields, two are dropdown fields and one is row sequence number.
AllowSorting is set to "true"

Each field is a TemplateField with respective SortExpressions.
ASP page looks something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVDoc" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GVDoc_ItemDataBound">
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sequence" SortExpression="Sequence" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblOrder" Text='<%# Eval("Sequence")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Property (Yes/No)" SortExpression="Property" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProperty" runat="server" DataValueField='<%# Eval("Property")%>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="No">No</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Valid (Yes/No)" SortExpression="Valid">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlValid" runat="server" DataValueField='<%# Eval("Valid")%>'>
                <asp:ListItem Value="No">No</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description")%>'></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

Each field is populated from the database. User is allowed to edit the text and change dropdown value. The edited data is not updated in the database. It is just to be able to see on the screen.

I need to allow sorting on the basis of each column. I am able to sort on all columns.

Code behind looks like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY File_Id) as Sequence, 'No' as Property, 'No' as Valid, File_Id, Name, Description FROM FILE

        Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(...ConnectionString...)
            Using comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
                conn.Open()
                Using da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
                    dt = New DataTable("table")
                    da.Fill(dt)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        GVDoc.DataSource = dt
        GVDoc.DataBind()
        Cache("ABC") = dt
        ViewState("Sequence") = "Sequence ASC"
        ViewState("Property") = "Property ASC"
        ViewState("Valid") = "Valid ASC"
        ViewState("Name") = "Name ASC"
        ViewState("Description") = "Description ASC"            
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub GVDoc_Sorting(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles GVDoc.Sorting
    If ViewState("Sequence").ToString().Contains(e.SortExpression) Then
        If ViewState("Sequence").ToString().Contains("ASC") Then
            RebindData(e.SortExpression, "DESC", "Sequence")
        Else
            RebindData(e.SortExpression, "ASC", "Sequence")
        End If
    ElseIf ViewState("Property").ToString().Contains(e.SortExpression) Then
        If ViewState("Property").ToString().Contains("ASC") Then
            RebindData(e.SortExpression, "DESC", "Property")
        Else
            RebindData(e.SortExpression, "ASC", "Property")
        End If
    ElseIf ViewState("Valid").ToString().Contains(e.SortExpression) Then
        If ViewState("Valid").ToString().Contains("ASC") Then
            RebindData(e.SortExpression, "DESC", "Valid")
        Else
            RebindData(e.SortExpression, "ASC", "Valid")
        End If
    ElseIf ViewState("Name").ToString().Contains(e.SortExpression) Then
        If ViewState("Name").ToString().Contains("ASC") Then
            RebindData(e.SortExpression, "DESC", "Name")
        Else
            RebindData(e.SortExpression, "ASC", "Name")
        End If
    ElseIf ViewState("Description").ToString().Contains(e.SortExpression) Then
        If ViewState("Description").ToString().Contains("ASC") Then
            RebindData(e.SortExpression, "DESC", "Description")
        Else
            RebindData(e.SortExpression, "ASC", "Description")
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RebindData(ColumnName As String, SortOrder As String, SortExpression As String)
    Dim dt As DataTable = CType(Cache("ABC"), DataTable)
    dt.DefaultView.Sort = ColumnName + " " + SortOrder
    GVDoc.DataSource = dt
    GVDoc.DataBind()
    ViewState(SortExpression) = ColumnName + " " + SortOrder
End Sub
```

I found various articles on different ways of sorting and I could sort it.

But my actual question is, I am able to sort by each column this way. But when I change the dropdown value or textbox value and then try to sort by any column then it sorts and displays the data that I get from database and not the one I just edited before sorting. Edited data goes away.

Is there a way to retain edited data even after sorting? I don't want to update the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit the values of data table then You should update your DataTable to cache.

Then call your RebindData it should work.

Please post your Row Update functions too. That will get some more clarity on whats happening after edits.

Comment: I don't have Row Update functions as I am not updating it to database. Column values are editable as they are dropdown and textboxes.

Comment: Ok atleast you should update your DataTable and rebind again to reflect the changes to GridView. 

You may use EditItemTemplate and an update button to commit the changes to DataTable. And use a label as ItemTemplate control for viewing purposes.

Comment: Updating DataTable and then doing a rebind worked for me. But now I have some other issue. I write a select query for updating the DataTable. Select query has values for each field but when I do databind on the gridview, the default value for dropdown field pops up and not the one that I edited and mentioned in the select query.

Comment: Ok on onrowdatabound fetch the value from datatable and select the dropdown accordingly. If the answer helped please mark as answer.

Answer (score 2):

After editing the data, I updated the DataTable, reassigned DataTable to Cache and then called the DataBind().

To retain the edited value for dropdown field, updated the dropdown field from DataTable in the RowDataBound.

Thanks for the solution.